# I get warning that "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements" with Apple Distribution Profile

Tags: xamarin.ios, app-store, apple-developer, apple-developer-account, app-store-distribution-profile

I have an app which is on AppStore. It is signed as ios distrubution.

After a while my certificates are expired on apple developer account. I revoked these and created again. And I started seeing two certificates (iOS Distribution and Distribution). I saw a warning that is "Distribution for use in Xcode 11 or later".

Now I will update my app on appstore but I can't sign it with "iOS Distrubution". Because my xcode version is 11.5.
When I  choose "iOS Distrubition" on my provisioning profile I can't sign my app.
When I  choose "Distrubition" on my provisioning profile I can sign my app. But in this case while I try to upload app to appstore, I get a warning that:

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'Development' for key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment' in 'Payload/...' is not supported."

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing app publish method. Previously I used to get ipa on my windows device and send it to app store with transporter from my mac. Now I created xcarchive file on mac. After I clicked this xcarchive and send it with xcode app publish tool. I signed my app there (xcode tool). And I didn't get any error with this way.

I didn't do anything on my provisioning profile. I used "Distrubition (for xcode 11)". And it worked with xcarchive. I don't know why it doesn't work with ipa.